# bower 1.0: what's the deal with .bower.json?

Tags: bower

I just upgraded to bower 1.0, did a `bower install` and found a bunch of new `.bower.json` files (note the leading period).

I found no references to `.bower.json` on the [changelog](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) or in the docs. Am I supposed to `.gitignore` these? They look very much like the original `bower.json` without the dot plus some extra metadata.

Comment: Basically you are supposed to ignore the whole `bower_components` folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't delete them because Bower uses its extra metadata. It was decided to leave the original bower.json file untouched and create a .bower.json one instead.

Comment: Thanks! Does it make sense to .gitignore it then?

Comment: @thatmarvin no, it's used by Bower.